# How to remove cell to left jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove item from the array by selecting a cell to the left of the button, I have tried using .previous selector but it doesn't work.

```js
var films = [];

function test2(e) {
  $("button").one("click", function(r) {
    r.preventDefault();

    var movie = $(e).attr("name");

    if (films.includes(movie)) {
      alert("This movie is in your basket")
    } else {
      films.push(movie);

      var r = films.length;

      $("#table1").empty();

      for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {
        $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + films[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");
      }
    }

  })


};

function newtest2(e) {


  $(e).parents('tr').remove();

}
```

```css
.cart {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.cart2 {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 19px;
  -moz-border-radius: 19px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart">
  <div class="cart2">
    <h1>Cart: </h1>
    <table id="table1">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<button name="Black Mirror" id="BM" id="carttest" onclick="test2(this)" value="Black Mirror" class="button1">Book now (Black Mirror)</button>
 <br>
<button name="Star Wars" id="SW" id="carttest" onclick="test2(this)" value="Star Wars" class="button1">Book now(Star Wars)</button>
```

I also have this bug that I have to click the button twice to fire the function.

Edit: 
Whenever the user clicks Order button, it runs the loop that creates the table with a button "remove" and adds the item to 'Films[]' Array. I want the remove button to remove the selected row but I also want it to remove the item from the array.

Comment: You should reform the question, specify which HTML element you want to remove by it's class or id.

Comment: Putting the click event handler in the function is causing the click twice to fire problem. Remove it from the function and put it in a jQuery document ready. Also, are you sure you want to use one and not on? One will only allow the event to fire once instead of each click?

Comment: It seems to me that your `newtest2()` function works as it should. It removes the whole table row. Why would you need to  remove specific cell?

Comment: I have updated the question. @LudovitMydla I want to remove the item from Array as well

Comment: Then put the code in the newtest2 to remove it form the array too.

Comment: @muasif80 That is my question, how can I remove it from the array

Comment: identifiers must be unique on DOM `id="carttest"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it needs a lot of fixes in your code.

First. Identifiers must be unique for each element.

2nd. When you push in array, you'll have to remove it too.

Here is what was missing in your code

```js
var films = [];


 $(".button1").click(function(e){
   

    var movie = $(this).attr("name");

    if (films.includes(movie)) {
      alert("This movie is in your basket")
    } else {
      films.push(movie);

      var r = films.length;

      $("#table1").empty();

     for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {
        $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + films[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");
      }
    }

  })


function newtest2(e) {
  $(e).parents('tr').remove();
  films.splice(films.indexOf($(e).parent().prev().text()), 1)
}
```

```css
.cart {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.cart2 {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 19px;
  -moz-border-radius: 19px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart">
  <div class="cart2">
    <h1>Cart: </h1>
    <table id="table1">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<button name="Black Mirror" id="BM"    value="Black Mirror" class="button1">Book now (Black Mirror)</button>
 <br>
<button name="Star Wars" id="SW"    value="Star Wars" class="button1">Book now(Star Wars)</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it! Got it working with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need prevent preventDefault() for a click

```
    var films = [];

    function test2(e) {
      //Don't need preventDefault()
      var movie = $(e).attr("name");

      if (films.includes(movie)) {
        alert("This movie is in your basket")
      } else {
        films.push(movie);

        var r = films.length;

        $("#table1").empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < r; i += 1) {
          $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + films[i] + "</td><td>" + "<button onclick='newtest2(this)'>Remove</button>" + "</td></tr>");
        }
      }

    };
    function newtest2(e) {
      const
      //parents of the clicked button
      parents = $(e).parents('tr'),
      //children of the parents
      children = parents.children(),
      //text content from first child
      text = children[0].textContent,
      //position of the text in array
      pos = $.inArray(text, films)

      //if position is not -1 (not found)
      if (pos !== -1 ) {
        //use position to remove item from the array
        films.splice(pos, 1)
      }
      console.log(`films:`,films)
      //remove the tr element from the view
      $(e).parents('tr').remove();
    }
```

The muasif80's code works just fine too.